Pass my private.key file to @ColumnTransformer in Spring Boot Hibernate
I have stored my private.key and public.key in resources folder and I have loaded it using
`    public static String loadPrivateKey() throws IOException {
        Resource privateKeyResource = new ClassPathResource("private.key");
        return readInputStream(privateKeyResource.getInputStream());
    }
    private static String readInputStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line);
            }
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();`

I have tested it using Systemout and the Keyloader is working properly.
But when I try to inject it into @ColumnTransformer, it gives the error java: element value must be a constant expression .
Below is my implementation part related to this in my entity class.
`    private static final String PUBLIC_KEY;
    private static final String PRIVATE_KEY;

    static {
        try {
            PUBLIC_KEY = KeyLoader.loadPublicKey();
            PRIVATE_KEY = KeyLoader.loadPrivateKey();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to load keys", e);
        }
    }

    private static final String readEx="pgp_pub_decrypt(asymdata, dearmor('" + PRIVATE_KEY + "'),'passphrase')";
    private static final String writeEx= "pgp_pub_encrypt(?, dearmor('"+PUBLIC_KEY+"'))";


    @Column(name="asymdata", columnDefinition = "bytea")
    @ColumnTransformer(
            read = readEx,
            write = writeEx)
    private String asymdata;`

Note: Here I have used pg-crypto to encrypt data in postgreSQL database using Asymmetric-key (public key) Encryption.
What I need is a way to get my private key from private.key file and pass it to ColumnTransformer annotation.
